# Send a message in real time with condition with PUG nodejs and socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I have a Mongo database with departure and arrival dates for a plane.

I want to post a real-time message about the plane. For example "not yet in the air", "The plane has landed".

I tried to follow the socket.io doc to get there. Here's what I did:

[CLIENT SIDE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7nHT9.png)

[BACKEND side](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N2sFz.png)

The problem is that I receive the messages but not in real time. I need to refresh the page to receive the new state of the plane.

Can you help me please?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. **Show us the code for your latest attempt** and where you got stuck. and explain why the result is not what you expected.  Edit your question to include the code, please don't add it in a comment, as it will probably be unreadable.
https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

It is better to show what is actually happening, rather than describing what you expect to happen.

Please include code and output as content for your question, not as pictures or external links.